# Entity Framework Core - Master Details Details query

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, master-detail

I saw a lot of post showing how to perform a query within Entity Framework to retrieve master details data, like this:

```
IQueryable<myobj> foo = _context.Foos.Include(x => x.FooDetails).Where(x => x.Id == fooId);
```

But I have to manage an harder case. A master details where every detail has its own details.
Something like:

Foo --> FooDetails --> FooDetailsInfo

Is this possible? If yes, how? Of course the dumb solution exists and it is use a loop. Is there a smarter way to reach this goal?

I tried to edit the line code

```
IQueryable<myobj> foo = _context.Foos.Include(x => x.FooDetails).Where(x => x.Id == fooId);
```

but I didn't write anything useful.

Comment: what is the pourpose of your query? What set of fields do you need I am asking this because it will return all fields - what do you need and what you don't need at all. It is not good for a performance and network trafic.Maybe you need better query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. After `Include` you can call `ThenInclude`

```
var foo = _context.Foos
    .Include(x => x.FooDetails)
    .ThenInclude(fd => fd.FooDetailsInfo)
    .Where(x => x.Id == fooId);
```